# Autoselect text with clipboard copy

Tags: javascript

I have this simple function that prompt the user to CTRL C a text in a paragraph. Should i put the AUTOSELECT text statement before or after the "prompt" so it will be easier for the user who will have only to copy to clipboard manually?

```
function copyInClipboard(text) {
  div.prompt("copy to clipboard?: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

Or, is there a CSS property that keeps the text selected by default? I didn't find such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no CSS property that keeps the text selected by default, but there is `node.select()` method which, when fired, selects text.
for example:

```
<input type="text" value="some text to be selected" onclick="this.select()" />
```

Comment: but i want the text to be selected by default, without a firing onclick event once the div appears.

Comment: No problem, on page load event, let's say, select your node that contains text and execute `select` method. Example with jQuery: `$('.myElement').get(0).select()`. You do not have to interact with page at all.

Comment: in addition to upper example, beware that `select()` is DOM and not jQuery method.